# Transparent console DllImport

Tags: c#, dllimport

I want be transparent the console, but I've a compilation error:
Transparency.cs(39,48): error CS0019: Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.IntPtr' and 'int'

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Transparency
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, uint crKey,byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex); 

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow(); 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
            int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
            uint LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
            //int LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;

            // Obtain our handle (hWnd)
            IntPtr Handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
            // Opacity = 0.5 = (255/2)
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need bitwise or which is the single pipe `|` as well as changing the return type for `GetWindowLong` to `int`. See [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong).